# docker is not found when running a docker command in entrypoint.sh

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I'm getting

> app_1       | ./entrypoint.sh: line 2: docker: command not found

when running this line of code in entrypoint.sh

```
docker exec -it  fullstacktypescript_database_1 psql -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE elitypescript"
```

How would i properly execute this command ?

**entrypoint.sh**

```
# entrypoint.sh
docker exec -it  fullstacktypescript_database_1 psql -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE elitypescript"
npm run seed # my attempt to run seed first before server kicks in. but doesnt work
npm run server
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build: ./server
    depends_on:
      - database
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    environment:
      PSQL_HOST: database
      PSQL_PORT: 5430
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-password}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-postgres}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB:-elitypescript}
    entrypoint: ["/bin/bash", "./entrypoint.sh"]
  client:
    build: ./client
    image: react_client
    links:
      - app
    working_dir: /home/node/app/client
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/node/app
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    command: npm run start
    env_file:
      - ./client/.env

  database:
    image: postgres:9.6.8-alpine
    volumes:
      - database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 3030:5439

volumes:
  database:
```

Comment: Why would you want to run a docker inside a docker? Don't you want to run the commands in the docker container, not in-in-in the docker inside the other docker? Why the double encapsulation? What is `fullstacktypescript_database_1` image? Is it running on host?

Comment: i just want to execute this command so that it initializes a database with a user, thats all i want to do.

Comment: `a database` _Where_ is this database? The word _where_ is very broad here - I'm asking about how to access it _and_ where is it virtually stored. So from the top - you want to connect from `app:` container to the postgres _service_ running inside `database:` container? `PSQL_PORT: 5430` The post `5430` is the port of _host_, where you _redirected_ port 5430 to 3030 of the continer. There is nothing listening on container on port 5430. Container still has open port 3030.

Comment: It may be a good time to read https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/ and https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#links and some good book about networking in linux.

Comment: The documentation for the [Docker Hub `postgres` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) may be informative, too: setting `POSTGRES_DB` should cause it to create the database for you, and if not, you can mount an SQL script into `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` that will get run on first initialization.

Comment: Have you installed `docker` in `app` image ?

Comment: I don't think so no. @Philippe  to better restate the main question, how would you go about initializing a db, before docker-compose is up and running. So in other words, say you have a repo, and you want postgres to work out of the box. without your users having to create a database, how would you go about doing this ? cause thats what im trying to achieve. with the script/

Comment: If you have not installed `docker`, how would `docker exec -it  fullstacktypescript_database_1...` work ?

Comment: i have docker installed on my local machine, i don't understand why do i need to install docker again in an image. its quite confusing.

Comment: This error message `app_1 | ./entrypoint.sh: line 2: docker: command not found` is because `docker` is not installed in `app` image.

Comment: how would you go about installing it in an image ?

Comment: ok will give it a shot

Comment: don't you think installing docker in an image is quite weird or unnecessary ?

Comment: i still get docker command not found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219513/discussion-between-philippe-and-barnowl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:10.6.0
COPY . /home/app
WORKDIR /home/app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
ENV DOCKERVERSION=18.03.1-ce
RUN curl -fsSLO https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/docker-${DOCKERVERSION}.tgz \
  && tar xzvf docker-${DOCKERVERSION}.tgz --strip 1 -C /usr/local/bin docker/docker \
  && rm docker-${DOCKERVERSION}.tgz
EXPOSE 5000
```

Answer (score 0):

You trying to run docker container inside of the docker container. In most cases it is very bad approach and you should to avoid it. But in case if you really need it and if you really understand what are you doing, you have to apply Docker-in-Docker(dind).

As far as I understand you, you need to run script `CREATE DATABASE elitypescript`, the better option will be to apply `sidecar` pattern - to run another one container with PostgreSQL client that will run your script.

Answer (score -1):

Link the containers together and connect using the hostname.

```
# docker-compose
services:
  app:
    links:
    - database
    ...
```

then just:

```
# entrypoint.sh
# the database container is available under the hostname database
psql -h database -p 3030 -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE elitypescript"
```

Links are a legacy option, but easier to use then networks.

Comment: will give this a shot

Comment: Then install psql. What did you expect? Before using (an advanced utility such as) docker, please first do some research in basic linux system administration.

Comment: i have psql installed on my local, how would i install psql on entrypoint.sh ?

Comment: `i have psql installed on my local` Does not matter. Docker runs containers in a separate filesystem space. `how would i install` the same way you would install it in the linux distribution the docker is running. I have no idea `build: ./server` what you are building there. The linuxfromscratch way would be to install from sources.

Comment: so do  `brew install postgresql` in the entrypoint.sh ? is that correct ?

Comment: You would do `brew install` if you have `brew` installed, typically on a macOS. I do not know what system are you running _inside the docker container_. (I highly doubt you have a macos docker image running).

Comment: im sorry this solution is not helping me.